# Angularjs Table data biding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ah1rcj65/10/)

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in schedule.days[0].entries" scope="row">
          <th>{{item.name}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="x in schedule.days.entries">{{x.value}}</td>
        </tr>
```

I am trying to create a dynamic table in angularjs. I got to a point where I am able to display the name and table row but in table data I am not able to bind the value object property. Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong on my ng repeat. I have been stuck on this for two days now some guidence would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: It's better to share your code here, instead of just pasting a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access `schedule.days.entries`, but `days` is an array, not an object. You're missing the index, e.g.

```
<td ng-repeat="x in schedule.days[0].entries">{{x.value}}</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0xsv2aq3/

Edit:

I was just showing how to access the values. If you want to take the values for the same name in different days and show it in the table, you can do something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/bray3gmd/

Comment: so why does it not match the table data with table correctly though you see it does not fit table properly

Comment: You are not iterating over the whole array, you are just repeating the first item in all `td`s.

Comment: so If i need to have the name stay constant isnt this the way to do it so i have have my name distinct